# Count number of lines in each file within current directory using a for loop?

Tags: bash, for

- If a parameter is provided as an input, script should only check number of lines for that input file, otherwise script should display number of lines for each file within that directory.
- The script file should be ignored i.e. the count for the script file should not be displayed.

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        for l in *.txt
        do
                echo $(wc -l $l)
        done
else
        for l in $*
        do
                echo $(wc -l $l)
        done
fi
```

But I am not allowed to explicitly mention the file type i.e *.txt - it must check all files except script file.

Comment: First of all, you don't need `echo $()`, just call `wc` directly

Comment: Second, use `$0`  variable to skip the script itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost got it. You can use `basename "$0"` to [find the name of the script from within the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name-in-a-bash-script), and print the line count of everything except that

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    for k in *
    do
        if [[ ! -d "$k" && "$k" != `basename "$0"` ]]
        then
            wc -l "$k"
        fi
    done
else
    for k in $*
    do
         wc -l "$k"
    done
fi
```

I took the liberty of

- Using `k` instead of `l` (not recommended for variable names I'm pretty sure although I can't find a link (it can be confused with `1`, `I`))
- Using 4 spaces for indentation instead of 8. In the end that is of course your decision, but I'd say 4 are more readable than 8.
- Quoting your variables. Highly recommended to avoid splitting variable names with spaces.
- Dropping the unnecessary `echo` like @Serg pointed out.

**EDIT** I added double brackets and a test for directories to ignore them as well to the `if` conditional.

Comment: How do we ignore directories?

Comment: `if [ ! -d "$k" ]`, `-d` stands for directory. I'll modify my answer. I needed to change it to double brackets to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" != 0 ]]; then
  # only process the names given to us
  wc -l "$@"
  exit
fi

# process all regular files in this directory, avoiding this script
for f in ./*; do
    if [[ "$f" != "$0" ]] && [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        wc -l "$f"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a script you can also combine three (3) commands in one line and print the results that you want.
Eg.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

If you don't want to search only in the current directory, but also count the lines recursively, you can remove the "-maxdepth 1" switch or change the number based on your needs.